# passport.js google oauth2 works locally but not when deployed

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, passport.js

I've set up a MERN app that uses the passport.js google-oauth2 strategy and everything works fine locally, but I'm unable to retrieve the user while deployed. I've tried all the solutions already given on this topic like adding the `sameSite` property to `cookieSession` or adding `app.set("trust proxy", 1)`  but I still can't make it work. I have double checked all enviroment variables and google redirect URIs.

Here is my code:

`passport.js`

```
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
        scope: ["profile"],
      },
      async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        done(null, profile);
      }
    )
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
};
```

`auth.js`

```
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }));

router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    failureRedirect: "/login/failed",
  })
);

router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
  // req.user is undefined here
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      error: false,
      message: "Log in success.",
      user: req.user,
      cookies: req.cookies,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({ error: true, message: "Not authorized." });
  }
});

router.get("/login/failed", (req, res) => {
  res.status(401).json({
    error: true,
    message: "Failed to log in.",
  });
});

router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect(process.env.CLIENT_URL);
});
```

`server.js`

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4420;

connectDB();
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    keys: ["key"],
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}.`));
```

`frontend request`

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/auth/login/success`, {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      },
    })
      .then(...)
  }, []);
```

Comment: What is your current output?